# Properly place two trees on a beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, minipage, forest

I'm relatively new to LaTeX. I've been struggling to place two trees on the same beamer slide at the right spot. I was able to get them centered but when I add bullets, the picture keeps moving up. Also, I had to reduce the overall size of the trees to make them fit side by side. But it does seem like there is space for the tree to be slightly bigger. Here is my code so far:

```
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{figure}
 \tiny
 \begin{minipage}[b][5cm]{0.35\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4,sibling distance=0pt]
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={circle, draw, fill=blue!80!darkgray!25}  
    [
    [
    [
    [ [ ] [ ] ]
    [ [ ] [ ] ] ]
    [
    [ [ ] [ ] ]
    [ [ ] [ ] ] ] ]
    [
    [
    [  [ ] [ ] ]
    [  [,fill={red} ] [ ] ] ]
    [
    [  [ ] [ ] ]                                                                        
    [  [ ] [ ] ] ] ] ] ]                                                             
    \end{forest}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][5cm]{0.5\linewidth}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,sibling distance=0pt]
   \begin{forest}
   for tree={circle, draw,fill=blue!80!darkgray!25,}      
   [
   [
   [
   [ [ ] [ ] ]
   [ [ ] [ ] ] ]
   [
   [ [ ] [ ] ]
   [ [ ] [ ] ] ] ]
   [
   [
   [  [,fill={red} ] [ ] ]
   [  [ ] [ ] ] ]
   [
   [  [ ] [ ] ]
   [  [ ] [ ] ] ] ] ] ]
   \end{forest}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Could someone please help center the figures so that adding bullets does not move the pictures up. Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're nesting tizkpictures, i.e. forest will already create a tikzpicure. And beamer has its own means to put stuff next to each other: columns. So you do not need the minipages either. And if you wan to fit everything, you may need to scale the forests further down.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{forest}
        for tree={circle, draw, fill=blue!80!darkgray!25,scale=.3,sibling distance=0pt}
        [
        [
        [
        [ [ ] [ ] ]
        [ [ ] [ ] ] ]
        [
        [ [ ] [ ] ]
        [ [ ] [ ] ] ] ]
        [
        [
        [  [ ] [ ] ]
        [  [,fill={red} ] [ ] ] ]
        [
        [  [ ] [ ] ]
        [  [ ] [ ] ] ] ] ] ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
       \begin{forest}
       for tree={circle, draw,fill=blue!80!darkgray!25,scale=.3,sibling distance=0pt}
       [
       [
       [
       [ [ ] [ ] ]
       [ [ ] [ ] ] ]
       [
       [ [ ] [ ] ]
       [ [ ] [ ] ] ] ]
       [
       [
       [  [,fill={red} ] [ ] ]
       [  [ ] [ ] ] ]
       [
       [  [ ] [ ] ]
       [  [ ] [ ] ] ] ] ] ]
       \end{forest}
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the `baseline` key is useful if the trees aren't the same height/depth @P.Routh.